# Angle of tangent line and line y=0, z=0 is constant

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

First a little bit of background. So my Calculus III professor asked us to prove a question similiar to:

> Show that the tangent lines to the regular parametrized curve $$
> \alpha \left( t \right) = \left( {3t,3t^2 ,2t^3 } \right)
> $$
>    make a constant angle with the line $y=0$ , $z=x$

Answered on another question asked previously: [basic question about angles of lines](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56594/basic-question-about-angles-of-lines?rq=1).

My professor asked a simliar question but set $\mathbf{z = 0}$

> Show that the tangent lines to the regular parametrized curve $$
> \alpha \left( t \right) = \left( {3t,3t^2 ,2t^3 } \right)
> $$
>    make a constant angle with the line $y=0$ , $z=0$

I solved this question using the vectors
$$\mathbf{a}=\left(\begin{matrix}1\\0\\0\end{matrix}\right)\mathbf{b}=\left(\begin{matrix}3\\6t\\6t^{2}\end{matrix}\right)$$

And found $\theta$ where $$\theta=\cos^{-1}\frac{(\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b})}{|\mathbf{a}||\mathbf{b}|}$$

After substitution, my final answer was:

$$\theta =\cos^{-1}\frac{1}{2t^{2}+1}$$

which is clearly not constant.

Thoughts on how I could do this differently to make the condition true? The alternative is that my professor made a typo when writing the question.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, your professor is wrong, but it works fine with the original problem. What is $\mathbf a\cdot\mathbf b$ now?

Comment: The dot product is (1)(3) + (0)(6t) + (0)($6t^{2}$). What works fine with the original problem? Meaning when z = x?

Comment: Yeah, I meant with $\mathbf a = (1,0,1)$. Then it's cool.